# How to Produce an Unbroken Emdash with Texttt

Tags: pdftex, symbols, typography, punctuation, typewriter

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}

emdash---

\vspace*{25pt}

Now, with the texttt command: \, \texttt{emdash---}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

How may I produce an (unbroken) emdash when using `\texttt`?

Comment: Use `fontspec`, together with something like `\setmonofont[Ligatures={TeX}]{My Font}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on @Ingmar's comment: Do consider employing the `fontspec` package -- and, if necessary, switching to LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX -- and loading the monospaced font of interest with the option `Ligatures=TeX`. (TeX implements endashes and emdashes as ligatures.) And, be sure to employ a monospaced font for which the differences between `-`, endash, and emdash are actually visually detectable -- that's *not* the case for Latin Modern Mono, as is demonstrated in the middle third of the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}

\begin{document}
\obeylines % just for this test document
Latin Modern Roman
--- -- -

\bigskip
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\texttt{Latin Modern Mono}
\texttt{--- -- -}

\bigskip
\setmonofont{Consolas}[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase]
\texttt{Consolas}
\texttt{--- -- -}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I had hoped to be able to accomplish the emdash with `pdflatex`; hence, the tag `pdftex` but I neglected to mention this in the title of the post. Thank you for your helpful and informative answer.

Comment: @jean-marie - I suppose you could achieve your goal of creating an emdash in the mono font face with pdflatex as well; the few mono fonts available for use with pdflatex simply don't show a vidually detectable difference between the outputs of `-`, `\textendash`,  and `\textemdash`. That's why I suggested using a font such as `Consolas`.