# How to Produce a Continuous Emdash with Pdflatex Using Texttt

Tags: pdftex, formatting, typography, punctuation, typewriter

I would like to know how one might extend the answer given in   [How to Produce an Unbroken Emdash with Texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650182/how-to-produce-an-unbroken-emdash-with-texttt/650196#650196) ---which requires `fontspec`; and thus, either `lualatex` or `xelatex`---that is applicable when compiling with `pdflatex`.

Consider the following code:

\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}
\texttt{How to make the texttt emdash---continuous when compiling with pdflatex?}
\end{document}

which produces

[image]

How may one obtain a continuous emdash when using `texttt` and compiling with `pdflatex`?

Comment: There are some "typewriter" fonts that are not monospace, and using one of them (provided it has an em-dash distinct from en-dash and hyphen) might be possible.  If a monospace font is desired, I would be inclined to define a `\ttemdash` constructed from as many hyphens as necessary, smushed together in a box which is the width of two ordinary characters. The following is not tested: `\newcommand{\ttemdash}{{\ttfamily\makebox{2em}{-\hss-\hss-}}}`.

Comment: Perhaps a raised rule?

Comment: The ligature in the sf version (lms) of the default fonts (Latin Modern) looks passable as a tt emdash: try `\ttfamily xxx \textsf{---} xxx`.

Comment: @Cicada `\textsf{---}`` seems to do the trick. Thank you. Perhaps you may consider posting it in the form of an answer.